# The verb after expression "should be such that"

Tags: verbs

Google has translated a sentence as:

> The number of building floors should be such that the resonance
>   frequency of the structure and the natural frequency of the site **is
>   not** the same.

I am not a native speaker of English, but the verb looks somewhat weird to me.
If the verb was not negative, I think the verb would be "**be**", as:

> The number of building floors should be such that the resonance
>   frequency of the structure and the natural frequency of the site **be** the same.

But, I don't have any idea now that the verb is in negative form.

Comment: Why do you think it should be **be** in the positive case?  You wouldn't say "The resonant frequency be the same".

Comment: Maybe I've made a mistake about the **be** immediately after should and could and this one. In comparison with Persian, it should not be __be__ :D

Comment: You know, I've learned about _am, is, are_ as present verbs. But, the above sentence is in some sense in the imperative form. For Ex. "It should be such that sth in the present or future be (or is?) changed".

Comment: So maybe it boils down to passive vs. active?  "It's important that you be quiet during the national anthem" vs. "It's important that you are quiet during the national anthem."  Also:  "It's important that you be solemn during the national anthem." ; "It's important that you NOT BE disruptive during the national anthem."

Comment: @malaprop So, if I've understood correctly, you say the latter sentence (with _be_) is grammatically correct, but is in passive form, right?

Comment: @Omid Yes, the sentence with "NOT BE" is correct, passive.  I still don't think "such that" requires subjunctive:  "Please position the lamp such that it IS upright."

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any verb expression requirement after "should be such that".  I think it should be "**are** not the same".  A and B are not the same.  C and C are the same.

For example:
If you want to outrun the police, your speed should be such that your car's speed and the police car's speed **are** not the same.

How about also consider this example:

Your boss says: The number of building floors should be such that the resonance frequency of the structure and the natural frequency of the site are the same.

You say:  But what about the building that we constructed next door?  Over there, the resonant frequency and the natural frequency **are not** the same.